# How do I delete records from a Datagrid as well in the database in ASP.NET using checkboxes?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, checkbox

How do I delete records from a DataGrid as well as the source database in ASP.NET using a checkbox to select them?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Lookup how to get the references to the selected items in the grid control.

Step 2:
Delete directly from the database using the references in step 1

Step 3: Refresh the grid control / page.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of what makes this a good programming site, it behooves you to at least try to solve the problem yourself first.

Once you have had a decent go and can provide some samples of the way you have attempted to resolve your problem then the people here will be glad to help.

Simply expecting others to gift you with a solution is not really what this site is all about.

My suggestion is to go and do some research, have a go at solving this yourself and then come back and ask a question related to the specific problem you are facing when attempting to resolve this.